# Rotating camera based on player's rotation

Tags: unity, c#, camera

I'm trying to have a camera rotate mirror the player's rotation, however, this isn't happening and the camera isn't rotating at all.  Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
public class PlayerActions:MonoBehaviour{
    Camera mainCamera;
    public Rigidbody player;
    public GameObject playerShot;
    public Transform shotSpawn;
    public Boundary boundary;

    public int speed;
    public int tilt;
    public int bank;
    public float fireRate;
    private float shotDelay;

    void Start(){
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
        player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate(){
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, moveVertical, 0f);
        player.velocity = move * speed;
        player.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(player.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax), Mathf.Clamp(player.position.y, boundary.yMin, boundary.yMax), 0f);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, player.velocity.x * -bank);
    }

    void Update(){
        if(Input.GetKey("space") && Time.time > shotDelay){
            shotDelay = Time.time + fireRate;
            Instantiate(playerShot, shotSpawn.position, shotSpawn.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

As it's working now, the player is rotating, but the camera isn't.

If you notice in the video linked below, the ship is rotating, but if you look at the static asteroid, you'll notice that the camera isn't.
[Not Rotating Game View](https://youtu.be/aeTF3AASZPQ)
[Not Rotating Editor View](https://youtu.be/HofxNQ3B6A8)

**Heirarchy**
[image]

**Inspector**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you're applying the rotation to the RigidBody of the player, and not to the GameObject transform. It also looks like you're modifying the velocity *and* position of the RigidBody, which may lead to unexpected results (e.g. the physics engine will be trying to reconcile the new velocity with the new position)

To answer your main question though, I think that simply applying your calculation to the GameObject and not the RigidBody should solve your issue, like so:

```
public class PlayerActions : MonoBehaviour{
    // ...
    void FixedUpdate(){
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, moveVertical, 0f);
        player.velocity = move * speed;
        player.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(player.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax), Mathf.Clamp(player.position.y, boundary.yMin, boundary.yMax), 0f);
        // Apply rotation to the GameObject
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, player.velocity.x * -bank);
    }

    void Update(){
        if(Input.GetKey("space") && Time.time > shotDelay){
            shotDelay = Time.time + fireRate;
            Instantiate(playerShot, shotSpawn.position, shotSpawn.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that there should now be no need to change the camera rotation, as Unity should deal with this for you

Comment: You mention applying the velocity and rotation to the rigidbody and that it would cause problems.  What should I be applying it to?  I'm new to Unity and am still trying to learn.

Comment: Actually re-reading your code I don't think this will be a problem. I initially read that you were setting the velocity (e.g. telling the physics engine how fast your object is going so that it can update the position) and then also updating the position. In actual fact what you're doing is setting the velocity, but then stopping the player going over certain boundaries. Plus, you're doing all of this in the fixed update, so it should be fine :-)

Comment: So then it should be working the way I have it?

Comment: It should be working so long as you use the code I provided above. It should just be a case of changing `player.rotation` to `transform.rotation` and removing the last line of the `Update` method (where you change the camera rotation)

Comment: Alright, I appreciate the help, I'll make that change and let you know if it works.

Comment: I've changed the rotation code to match what you've told me to, but the camera still is not rotating.

Comment: Is the player actions component attached to the Interceptor game object? Might be worth upgrading a gif or video of what you're seeing

Comment: It is, and I'm working on uploading a video.  I'll also include an image of the player's inspector.

Comment: I've added a link to the video showing what it's doing and added a screenshot of my player's inspector panel.

Comment: From the video it certainly looks like the camera is rotating, just not as much. From your edited question I can see that you have `mainCamera.transform.rotation = player.rotation;`, but have change `player.rotation` to `transform.rotation`. Does this mean that `mainCamera.transform.rotation = player.rotation;` is still present in your current script?

Comment: Oh, no, I meant to take that part out.  That's not in my script anymore, I just forgot to remove it.  So since it looks like it is rotating, but not as much as it should be, should I be changing the camera's rotation directly and by a different value?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so. When you rotate the parent of a child, the child should rotate by the same amount. So you have a video of what's going on in the editor window, so I can see how much the camera is moving by? It's a little disorientating seeing it in the game view

Comment: I don't, but I can make one and have it uploaded in an hour or so.

Comment: I uploaded the video, but I noticed something odd.  When looking at the rotation on the child camera, when the player rotates, the rotation of the camera doesn't rotate.  Is it not supposed to?

Comment: Off the top of my head I can't remember whether that's expected or not. It looks like your camera has a player follow script attached to it. What happens if you disable that script?

Comment: Ok, the attached script was the problem. It's working correctly now. Thank you for working through this with me.

Comment: No problem at all, glad I could help :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49221/discussion-between-hobnob-and-robert).

Answer (score 1):

1. "mainCamera" is accessing the Gameobject with the Tag "MainCamera".

To see if its the right camera use:
Debug.Log(mainCamera);

2.
As far as I understood you want the Camera to move always behind the player (like 3rd person) or inside the player (like in a FPS)

if you want that:

You can either Parent the Camera to the Player.
(So the Player Gameobject has a child Gameobject: "Camera")

Or you can Calculate the current position of the Camera.
Calculating a Parent/Child relationsship is for pretty advanced users though.

EDIT:
3. 
As far as I can see, you already parented already a camera to another GameObject ( I assume its the player)

Try using not the rigidbody.rotation but "transform.rotation"

be warned: It should already work if the camera is parented.
are you sure you are not modifying the camera position/rotation somewhere else?

Comment: Thank you.  As far as your 3rd edit, yes, the camera is a child of the player, which is why I'm confused as to why it's not rotating with the player, but it may be because I need to use the transform rather than rigidbody like you said.  I am trying to keep the camera "behindish" the player.  I'll have to test your solution tonight, but I'll also add video to my question to better show what's going on.  I'm definitely not skilled enough to try to do the calculation stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Just write mainCamera.forwar = player.forward in your FixedUpdate that will make the camera face the back of the player.